# Sum of given series

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sum for series : `1 − 1 / 2 + 1 / 3 − 1 / 4 + · · · + 1 / 99 − 1 / 100 ** 2` with python.

My code is -

```
psum = 0
nsum = 0
for k in range(1,100):
    if k%2 == 0:
        nsum += 1.0/k
    else:
        psum += 1.0/k

print psum - nsum - 1.0/100**2
```

The output is 0.69807217931

I don't have the answer and just want to verify if I am doing it right.

**This is not a homework question but just random Python practice.**

Comment: Are you sure you're only meant to square the last term? (Well, if it isn't homework, then it's up to you I guess :) )

Comment: yes, it is the last term only, I am doing this question from one random pdf that I got from internet, it is called "A Short Course in Python for Number Theory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works fine, but why not just use one "summing" variable (call it `total`, as a matter of good practice, since there is a built-in called `sum` which you don't really want to hide), and actually add or subtract from it at each step?

Alternately (pun intended!), actually **use** that `sum` function. The `range` function can be used to skip every other number, too.

```
>>> sum(1.0/k for k in range(1, 100, 2)) - sum(1.0/k for k in range(2, 100, 2)) - (1.0/100**2)
0.6980721793101952
```

Or, as steveha shows, you can use logic to sort out whether to add or subtract the number based on whether it's divisible by 2, and handle it with a "weighted" sum (adding 1.0/k or -1.0/k as appropriate). This is why you should learn more math as a programmer :)

Comment: I perfer the two sums to the ternary operator in a single sum ... +1

Comment: Really? I honestly don't. Although `sum(-1.0**(k+1) / k ...)` is a better model for what I'm accustomed to seeing, actually :) since that's how mathematicians normally write it. However, exponentiating negative numbers doesn't work like that in Python...

Comment: Yeah -- Just a matter of preference I guess.  If python's ternary operator was more C-like, I might perfer it, but as it is, I don't like seeing "control" statements inside my "mathematical" formulas.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I believe

```
import math
print math.log(2)
```

would do the trick.

Comment: That's the limit of the summation; here we're looking for a specific number of terms.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: the OP wanted to verify if their code works correctly, this is the shortest way to check. Since your answer is on the top I'd suggest you edit this info in (WP link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series)

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(1.0/k if k % 2 else -1.0/k for k in xrange(1, 100)) - 1.0/100**2
```

The above code does the same thing as your code, and gets the same answer.

Why does the series use 1/k from 1 through 99, and then use 1/k**2 just for k == 100?

Comment: I love list comprehension but forget to use them when I see a problem, maybe i need to start using them more :)

Comment: This is definitely what I would normally do, but I assumed the OP's math skills were not up to understanding a weighted sum...

Comment: In this case, it is a "generator expression".  A list comprehension builds a list, but a generator expression just yields up values one by one.  You can iterate a genexp just as easily as a listcomp, and it is more efficient, since Python doesn't need to build a list that will be used once and then deleted.

Comment: Also note that this gets the very last term wrong on python 2.x unless you `from __future__ import division` (in python 2, `1/100 == 0` because it does integer division)

Comment: I am new to Python, just completed few lectures of MIT CS class with Python, that's why I called a generator function a list comprehension, but soon I will know it well :)

Comment: @mgilson, excellent point.  Note I got it right in two out of three places, but just missed one... oops, sorry.  I tested the above code, and it worked; but I tested it in an instance of Python that has future division!  I'll fix the example to use 1.0 so it works properly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being new to Python!  I wasn't trying to make you feel like a newbie; I just wanted to let you know exactly what is going on in my code sample, and make sure you know the proper term in case you want to Google search to learn more about it.  I really love generator expressions in combination with functions like `sum()`!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see if you're doing it right is to try it with a much shorter series, one that you can check by hand.  For example, use range(1, 5) and see if it gives the answer you expect.

For style tips, you can use xrange instead of range.  xrange is nice because it just returns each number as it's needed, while range creates a big list of all the numbers.  If you did this for range(1, 1000000), it would use up a lot of memory, while xrange wouldn't.

You could also get away with just one variable for the sum instead of two, I think.

Comment: This is 2.x specific; in 3.x, `range` does what `xrange` used to do, and there is no more `xrange`. (To get what `range` used to do, you can apply `list` to the result.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion.
little but more LOC then @steveha but more generic.

```
getx=lambda x:(1.0/x)*((-1)**((x%2)+1))
num=100
sum((getx(x) for x in xrange(1,num)))+getx(num)**2
0.688172179310195
```